# Rails Simple Form Association submission not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a problem with has_many relationships setting up forms that do not update the values after submission.

**Example**

Upon submission of a new character, vn_id does not get updated and in Rails Consoles when I try to check for characters in a Vn, it returns empty.

I am trying to set up a form for characters which belongs to Vn which will be linked through the association but upon submission, it is not linked to Vn.

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates :summary, :presence => true
    belongs_to :vn
end

class Vn < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characters
  validates :name, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :characters
end
```

Form to create a new Character

```
<%= simple_form_for @character do |f| %>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <%= f.input :summary,input_html: {style: "height:150px;"} %>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <%= f.association :vn, as: :check_boxes %>
    </div>
      <%= f.button :submit , class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

**Controllers**

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @character = Character.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @character = Character.new
    end

    def create  
        @character = Character.new(char_params)  
        if @character.save

        else
            render :action=>"new"
        end

    end

    private
        def char_params
        params.require(:character).permit(:name, :summary,:voiceactor,:vn_name,vn_id: [])
    end

end

class VnsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @vn = Vn.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @vn = Vn.new
    end

    def create  
        @vn = Vn.new(vn_params)  
        if @vn.save

        else
            render :action=>"new"
        end

    end

    private
        def vn_params
    def vn_params
        params.require(:vn).permit(:name, :summary,:genre,:developer,:rating,vn_id: [])
    end

    end

end
```

Submission unpermitted vn_id

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"O2s6GVs77GGUMC5u3eZ9ebv/0l5u0MwP44yS8WGCQnjgwSgHfkbCmhEOUo6WKIMSMo5IfDuNYtMzyphnT/5cwQ==", "character"=>{"name"=>"2222", "voiceactor"=>"111", "summary"=>"one two tthee", "vn_id"=>"32"}, "commit"=>"Create Character"}
Unpermitted parameter: vn_id
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "characters" ("name", "summary", "voiceactor", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "2222"], ["summary", "one two tthee"], ["voiceactor", "111"], ["created_at", "2015-10-23 10:34:00.285447"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-23 10:34:00.285447"]
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code in the question?

Comment: Added the controller code

Comment: Try adding `vn_id` in `char_params`.

Comment: still not getting a link between vn and characters when testing in rails console

Comment: Can you post the `params` that generated in the log while submitting the form in the question?

Comment: it says vn_id is not permitted, I added vn_id to vn_params and I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Do you get the same issue after adding `vn_id` to `char_params`?

Comment: Yes, I also restarted the server and tried it again and am still receiving the same error,

Comment: Wait. Try `vn_id: []` instead.

Comment: I'm not receiving the unpermitted error anymore but when I try calling `vn.characters` it doesn't show a record. I updated the `POST` log. I also tried creating a new character through `vn.characters.new` and it shows the record correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is **you're trying to permit an array for a singular association**.

---

The `f.association` input is for your `belongs_to` association, so why would it allow multiple records?

You can even see how this works [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

[image]

The above are methods **only for `has_many`**

In short, **they don't exist for `belongs_to`**

---

Thus, when you call `f.association :vn`, you're populating an attribute `vn_id` which can then be associated in your database.

The only time you'd have `vn_ids` is if you used `has_many` etc.

This means...

```
def character_params
    params.require(:character).permit(:vn_id) 
end
```

with

```
f.association :vn
```

... should work

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, changing `vn_id: []` in CharactersController back to `:vn_id` worked.

Comment: I have no idea, it could be because I did not reset my local server when adding :vn_id.